# ORACLE - tables

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

After entering code to create a new table in SQL ORACLE, would the changes be saved if I was to log out of the SQL Session?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "entered" If by "entered" you meant that a CREATE TABLE statement had been exectuted. If by "entered" you meant typed into a SQL code window of some tool, (TOAD, SQL Developer, etc.) then the answer is not clear without more details, like which tool.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, your table definitions are saved; Oracle [DDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Definition_Language) has an implicit transaction*.  Other databases, such as PostrgreSQL, do have [transactional DDL](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Transactional_DDL_in_PostgreSQL:_A_Competitive_Analysis), but with Oracle, it is automatic, so be careful.

* [Oracle Transaction Management](http://www.stanford.edu/dept/itss/docs/oracle/10g/server.101/b10743/transact.htm#i8072): *If the current transaction contains any [DML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Manipulation_Language) statements, Oracle first commits the transaction, and then runs and commits the DDL statement as a new, single statement transaction.*

Answer (score 4):

The correct answer is that Oracle DDL uses an implicit transaction - there's no opportunity to the transaction back, it's immediately committed.

Answer (score 1):

In short, "yes".  DDL statements are committed immediately after execution.  If your script also includes INSERT statements to populate those tables, then those would not be saved without a commit of their own.

Answer (score 0):

Umm, what? Yes all changes to Data and Table structures are immediately saved (unless part of a transaction, which waits till the end of the transaction to permanently save)
The things that are dependent upon your Session are session variables and session settings.

Comment: Oracle DDL statements are always there own transactions. They can not be part of a larger transaction that is latter commited or rolled back.